# React-Native Header Title and Tab Navigator

Tags: react-native, react-navigation, react-navigation-bottom-tab

I’ve a problem I cannot find an answer to, even though I’ve found similar problems with answers.

Basically, I pull a name (and other info) from a database.  I then navigate to a screen (Screen A) in a tab navigator.  I place the name into the header title of that screen (needed a stack navigator to do that I discovered from this site).  I then have a second tab (Screen B) I can navigate to and want that same name placed in the header title there.

While on Screen B I also need to change the name and have that placed back into the header title of both Screen A and Screen B.

How do I do this?  I have example code below that hopefully explains in more detail.

**App.js**

```
import React from 'react';
import { Text, View } from 'react-native';
import { NavigationContainer } from '@react-navigation/native';
import { createStackNavigator } from '@react-navigation/stack';
import { createBottomTabNavigator } from '@react-navigation/bottom-tabs';

import { HomeScreen, ScreenA, ScreenB } from './ui/screens.js';

const AStack = createStackNavigator();

function ScreenAStack(headerProps) {
    return (
        <AStack.Navigator>
            <AStack.Screen name="Screen A" component={ScreenA} />
        </AStack.Navigator>
    );
}

const BStack = createStackNavigator();

function ScreenBStack(headerProps) {
    return (
        <BStack.Navigator>
            <BStack.Screen name="Screen B" component={ScreenB} />
        </BStack.Navigator>
    );
}

const BottomTab = createBottomTabNavigator();

function Tabs() {
    return (
        <BottomTab.Navigator
            screenOptions={{ headerShown: false }}
        >
            <BottomTab.Screen name="Screen A Stack" options={{ title: "Screen A" }}>
                {(props) => (
                    <ScreenAStack {...props} />
                )}
            </BottomTab.Screen>
            <BottomTab.Screen name="Screen B Stack" options={{ title: "Screen B" }}>
                {(props) => (
                    <ScreenBStack {...props} />
                )}
            </BottomTab.Screen>
        </BottomTab.Navigator>
    );
}

const Stack = createStackNavigator();

const App = () => {
    return (
        <NavigationContainer>{
            <Stack.Navigator>
                <>
                    <Stack.Screen name="Home Screen" options={() => ({ headerShown: true })} component={HomeScreen} />
                    <Stack.Screen name="Screen A Tabs" options={() => ({ headerShown: false })} component={Tabs} />
                </>
            </Stack.Navigator>
        }</NavigationContainer>
    );
}

export default App;
```

**screens.js**

```
import React, { useEffect } from 'react';
import { View, Text, TextInput, StyleSheet, Button, } from 'react-native';

export function HomeScreen({ navigation }) {

    // Get name from server using api and send to Screen A.

    navList = (item) => {
        navigation.navigate("Screen A Tabs", {
            screen: 'Screen A Stack',
            params: {
                screen: 'Screen A',
                params: { item },
            },
        });
    }

    return (
        <View style={{ flex: 1, alignItems: 'center', justifyContent: 'center' }}>
            <Text>Home Screen.</Text>
            <Button title="Go to Tab Screen" onPress={() => navList({name: "Name here!"})} />
        </View>
    );
}

export function ScreenA({ route, navigation }) {

    // Place name into header title.

    useEffect(() => {
        navigation.setOptions({
            title: route.params.item.name,
        });
    }, [route]);

    return (
        <View style={{ flex: 1, alignItems: 'center', justifyContent: 'center' }}>
            <Text>Screen A</Text>
        </View>
    );
}

export function ScreenB({ navigation }) {

    // Update header title with new name and update name on server using api.

    const [newName, setNewName] = React.useState("");

    return (
        <View style={{ flex: 1, alignItems: 'center', justifyContent: 'center' }}>
            <Text>Screen B</Text>
            <TextInput
                value={newName}
                onChangeText={newName => setNewName(newName)}
                placeholder="Type new name here."
            />
            <Button title="Change Name" onPress={() => console.log("Change name to " + newName)} />
        </View>
    );
}
```

Comment: @Engr.Aftab Ufaq your answer doesn't solve the problem.  If I place navigation.setOptions in DialerScreen, it updates the header in DialerScreen, but how do I get that change back to SearchScreen?

Answer (score 0):

I will give a short answer. your do not need to create a separate stacks for a single screen. here you can create a simple bottom tab navigator. just a sample.

```
<Tab.Navigator
    initialRouteName="SearchScreen"
    backBehavior="initialRoute"
    screenOptions={{headerShown: false}}
    >
    <Tab.Screen
        name="SearchScreen"
        component={SearchScreen}
        options={{
            headerShown: false,
            tabBarLabel: 'Search',
            tabBarIcon: 'search',
        }}
    />

    <Tab.Screen
        name="DialerScreen"
        component={DialerScreen}
        options={{
            headerShown: false,
            tabBarLabel: 'Dialer',
            tabBarIcon: 'dialer',
        }}
    />

</Tab.Navigator>
```

after this create a simple stack and add this bottom or top tab navigator like this

```
 <Stack.Screen
    name="Home"
    component={TopTabNavigator}
    options={{headerShown:true}}
/>
```

you can change title like this

```
onPress={() => {
     if (item.is_analog) {
        navigation.setOptions({title: 'Analog Speedo Meter'});
     } else {
        navigation.setOptions({title: 'Digital Speedo Meter'});
     }
 }}
```

cheers